# How to calculate central tendencies of grouped data

Tags: r

[image: R code question]

I am new to r programming.I need help how to find the mean,median,mode of grouped data in the above question

Comment: what is your math definition of `central tendency`?

Comment: Can you elaborate more will be helpful to help.you can try simple ```summary(data)```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tapply`:

```
height <- c(150, 145, 170, 188, 190, 171)
num_men <- c(4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 3)

# mean:
tapply(height, num_men, mean)
  3   4   6 
177 169 145

# median:
tapply(height, num_men, median)
  3   4   6 

# sd:
tapply(height, num_men, sd)
       3        4        6 
11.26943 26.87006       NA
```

To calculate the mode, use this (credit to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_mean_median_mode.htm):

Define function:

```
getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

Insert function into `tapply`:

```
tapply(height, num_men, getmode)
3   4   6 
170 150 145
```